# Passing a local variable into an anonymous function in Javascript (D3 filtering)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scope, anonymous-function, local-variables

I'm trying to pass a local variable (a dictionary) into a D3 filter function, but am having little success in doing so.

```
d3appendedElement.on("click", function(d){

    var county_list = state_retriever[d.id];    
    //county_list is a dictionary: 
    //county_list = {"56001": true, "56003": true, "56005": true,...}

    embedGroup.filter(function(e){
        console.log(e); 
        //e = ["16079", -0.36402252840408394, -0.5303157467831482]
        //here, I would like to have access to county_list. However, I do not.

        //The following does not work; I get
        // `Uncaught ReferenceError: county_list is not defined`
        return e[0] in county_list;
    });
}
```

`county_list` is a dictionary of strings matched to `true`. `embedGroup` is a d3 object, and I am trying to filter each data point (filter `["16079", -0.36, -0.53]` on **16079**) based on whether it is in the `county_list` dictionary.

Is there a way to do this without making `county_list` a global variable?

Comment: can you provide a functional snippet, a fiddler/plunker link?

Comment: Given your snippet, `country_list` **is** accessible inside the filter: https://jsfiddle.net/aza7e3w7/ You'll have to provide an example reproducing the error.

Comment: I am not sure actually what is the issue. I redid your fiddle to more closely reflect my issue, and it works perfectly in the [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asuprem1671/b1fnmcoy/6/). However, from my local instance, from [this short imgur gallery](https://imgur.com/gallery/ycpgM) it doesn't seem to be the case.